# Log Headers in AWS load balancer logs or perform ops on 5xx series

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am working with AWS set up for REST-APIs like below:

> `Caller -> ALB -> EC2 -> myApplication.war`

The APIs use OAuth 2.0 hence the access token is passed as part of request headers as `Authorization`. The access token uniquely identifies the client that's calling the REST endpoint.

**What I want to do?**

- Log the authorization header at the load balancer level (which I think is not possible)
- Identify a way to capture the access token for the REST call at load balancer level so that I know which all access tokens received a 5XX status code